# Can I suppress all code analysis messages for a certain class?

Tags: .net, code-analysis, suppression

Whenever I call my logger in a method, e.g.

```
_logger.Debug("Connecting to database...");
```

I get the warning:

```
CA1303 : Microsoft.Globalization: 
Method 'Database.Connect()' passes a literal 
string as parameter  'message' of a call to 'ILogger.Debug(string)'. 
Retrieve the following string(s) from a resource table instead: 
"Connecting to database...".
```

Is there a way to suppress this warning every time I use a function of `ILogger`?
I really don't want to suppress it in every method I'm using it.

Comment: Or, you could get the string from a resource table instead and then you won't have any warnings anymore?

Comment: I know, but I don't want to do that for log messages.

Comment: Prefix the string with @ to mark it as a literal, .Debug(@"Connecting to database...")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither FxCop/VS Code Analysis nor the CA1303 rule are configurable to ignore particular targets in this way.  You basically have three options:

1. Suppress the violations individually,
2. Disable the rule, or
3. Substitute a custom rule that behaves the way you would prefer.

I tend to lean toward #3 for this sort of thing, but ymmv...  Also, if you feel strongly that you ought to be able to control the CA1303 behaviour, this is something to consider requesting at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio or http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio.

Answer (score 15):

If you control the `ILogger` interface, you can leverage the `Localizable` attribute with a value of false to indicate the value is not localizable.

For example:

```
void Info([Localizable(false)] string message);
```

Comment: Exactly what was needed. Should have been marked as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue and found that the easiest solution was to rename my logging method's parameter from "message" to something else.

[CA1303](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182187.aspx) will only trigger if the relevant parameter or property name contains "Text", "Message" or "Caption". If the parameter is passed to `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine`, the parameter also cannot be named "value" or "format".

Comment: Thanks. While I think the proper solution is to use `[Localizable(false)]`, System.ComponentModel.LocalizableAttribute is unfortunately not available in Portable Class Libraries. So for me changing the parameter name from `message` to `logMsg` solved it (then I just had to suppress CA1704:IdentifiersShouldBeSpelledCorrectly in the log interface).

Answer (score 2):

If you apply the GeneratedCode attribute to a class, Code Analysis will not analyze your class.